# C++: Creating one list out of two lists with subclasses (typedefs)

Tags: c++, list, subclass, typedef

I have two lists (listsub1 & listsub2) and I want to combine them with push_back to one (listclass).

```
class Subclass1 : public Basisclass {...};
class Subclass2 : public Basisclass {...};

//...

typedef std::list<std::shared_ptr<Basisclass> > ListClass;
typedef std::list<std::shared_ptr<Subclass1> > ListSubclass1;
typedef std::list<std::shared_ptr<Subclass2> > ListSubclass2;

//...

ListSubclass1 listsub1 = ...
ListSubclass2 listsub2 = ...

//...

ListClass listclass;
for (const std::shared_ptr<Subclass1> pSubclass1 : listsub1)
{
    listclass.push_back(pSubclass1);
}
for (const std::shared_ptr<Subclass2> pSubclass2 : listsub2)
{
    listclass.push_back(pSubclass2);
}
```

How do I do this correctly?
Here is the error message:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::list<std::shared_ptr<Basisclass> >::push_back(const std::shared_ptr<Subclass1>&)'
      listclass.push_back(pSubclass1);
```

Comment: Looks like you need to upcast pointers from `Subclass1` to `Basicclass`. Rather unfortunate to have lists of derived classes, if you're going to flatten it anyway.

Comment: [`std::static_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast)

Comment: The upcast should happen implicitly. The error suggests that `Subclass1` is not derived from `Basisclass`, but as the code is incomplete we can't tell.

Comment: Both classes (Subclass1 and Subclass2) are definitely subclasses of Basisclass.

class Subclass1 : public Basisclass
{}

Comment: That's still not complete code. I've voted to close this question because it doesn't meet the guidelines for this site, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @JonathanWakely No cast will happen.  `shared_ptr<base>` is an unrelated type to `shared_ptr<derived>`.  No implicit upcast will happen like you get the a `derived*` going to a `base*` as those types are actually covariant.

Comment: @NathanOliver [wanna bet?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78b4a604a5497123) What do you think constructor (9) is for at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr ?

Comment: @JonathanWakely Good call.  I forgot about that constructor.  Not sure why this nis not working then since [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c6ed2f9519b414b) works.

Comment: @NathanOliver, like I already said above: it means that `Subclass1` is not derived from `Basisclass` (or that they're only forward declared so the derivation isn't visible to the compiler, which is effectively the same).

Comment: @quappo the code above is still not complete. I've already linked to a complete version that works fine (see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78b4a604a5497123) so you must be doing something different that you aren't showing. We're not psychic, **show your code**.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help!

I forgot to include the header files :/
Now it works properly!

Comment: Which is why you're supposed to show the **complete** code you're compiling, not what you *think* you're compiling. You thought the classes where derived from `Basisclass` and you showed us code where that was true but it wasn't what you were really compiling. We can't help you if you lie to us.